# Popped/burst/splashed usage

Tags: vocabulary

A person was handling a small plastic can filled with small beads. His hand fumbled and all the beads popped burst and spread all over the floor.

What are correct verbs describe this movement?

> 1. The beads popped burst all over the floor.
> 2. He popped burst the beads and they are now all over the floor.
> 3. The beads splashed(?)

Comment: When I hear 'splash', I mainly think of liquids.

Comment: Is the can sealed? Pressurized? Open?

Comment: You can't just run two verbs together like that - you can say something popped, or it burst, but you can't say "it popped burst".

Answer (score 2):

If the can (with no top) was tilted and the beads fell out, that is not "bursting".
*bursting* would be (for example) when a sealed container with some contents builds up pressure inside the container, so that it would break open.

I would say:

> The beads **spilled** all over the floor.

[*spill*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spill):

> 1. To cause or allow (a substance) to run or fall out of a container.
> 2. To scatter (objects) from containment: *spilled the armload of books on the desk*.

Answer (score 1):

It would just be "The beads burst all over the floor." Popped burst is just two verbs in front of each other, and is neither necessary nor (as far as I know) grammatically correct.